# How to perform silent and unattended installation

Tags: .net, publishing, silent-installer, unattended-processing

I have published this application from .net 4 (it is mixture C# and VB) and here I've got the `.exe` file. So now I have the requirement for it to be installed silently and unattended on the users' computers. Problems:

1. I run the `setup.exe`, it installs the application and opens it automatically afterwards - I do not want that.
2. The progress bar of the installation is shown - I do not want that.

I have followed [this guide](http://unattended.sourceforge.net/installers.php), which seems pretty thorough and explains well, but none of the commands worked out. I tried probably all of the options, but I always get the same result, that I don't want - progress bar shown and application opens automatically after installation.

It seems that simply `...exe /s` or `...exe /s /v/qn` shall do the job, but not... 
I also took a look [at this](http://kb.flexerasoftware.com/doc/Helpnet/isxhelp12/IHelpSetup_EXECmdLine.htm).

So any suggestions?

Comment: In general, it is undesirable to do a completely silent installation, since it provides a vector for malicious code. I would imagine there's a need for this to install things remotely across a network, but in that instance, there'd be no harm in declaring the installation on-screen.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried Capital S instead of lower case s. I read some where that it is case sensitive so try ...exe /S . Also your setup file may not support /s read this http://support.arkhon.com/help/webhelp/install/creating_silent_installs.htm